# Clojure to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I got a problem with Clojure. I don't program in Clojure or ClojureScript, but I need some Clojure to compile to JavaScript. I followed the Getting Started https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Windows-Setup (set all the .jar files up) and downloaded the git repo. But I don't really understand how to compile my "project".clj to JavaScript. Would be glad if anybody can help!

Answer (score 2):

Once you've installed [leiningen](http://leiningen.org/)  ([there is a windows installer also](https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein.bat) )you have to cd into the project and then:

```
cd  'project-name'
lein cljsbuild once
```

And the clojurescript will be compiled follow the project.clj compilation configuration details. If these steps don't do the expected compile work, then you'd have to publish some extra details about your project.clj configuration

PS: Be sure to have installed leininguen version 2+ . (On the terminal: `lein -version`)

Comment: tyvm, hat worked for me. I also found a website for that. http://squirrel.pl/blog/2013/01/02/get-started-with-clojurescript-with-leiningen-templates/